# Javascript regex conditional statement when two of same character detected in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression that detects when a string has two periods. When this condition has been met, it deletes all the characters up to (and including) the first period.

string:
`"abc.def.ghi"`

abc. would be removed, and we have:
`"def.ghi"`

I've recently learned I can't use conditionals in javascript regex. Is there a solution in regular javascript?

Regex code I have so far
   `/\.[^.]*\.?/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[^.]*\.(?=[^.]*\.)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/36

```
var re = /^[^.]*\.(?=[^.]*\.)/;
var str = 'abc.def.ghi\n\n';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Nice regex,  but the `g` and `i` flags are unnecessary here.

Comment: Eureka! You sir are a scholar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = "abc.def.ghi"
newStr = str.replace(/^[^.]*\.(.*?\.)/, '$1') // def.ghi
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eH1pI3/1)